# Compare two csv files in groovy

Tags: sql, bash, groovy, compare

I am trying to create a comparison script to compare 2 SQL tables.
Each of these two tables has around 4.000 rows.

I used Groovy to import the tables and store them as CSV files.
For both CSVs the first column is the ID which I need to use for the comparison.

For every id number there might be many rows.
The number of rows for an ID in one CSV can be different for the same ID in the other CSV.

Eg:

```
   CSV1    -     CSV2
---------  -  ----------
ID, Value  -  ID , value
1 , A      -  1  , A
1 , B      -  2  , A
2 , A      -  2  , B
3 , B      -  3  , C
```

So in the above case, I would expect an output like

```
ID,Value, FoundIn
 1, A   , both
 1, B   , 1
 2, A   , both
 2, B   , 2
 3, B   , 1
 3, B   , 2
```

So far I haven't managed to come across a suitable way of doing that comparison in Groovy.

I have tried by nesting bash inside groovy and use diff command, as:

```
"println "diff -sw /home/testFolder/file1.txt /home/testFolder/file2.txt".execute().text
```

but diff does line-by-line comparison which in this case doesn't work.

Is there a better way to do this?

My knowledge of programming is very narrow and I would gladly use some help.
I hope I have given you enough info to understand the problem, but if not, I would be happy to provide more.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Just to make it a bit clearer

Eg:

```
   CSV1    -     CSV2
---------  -  ----------
ID, value  -  ID , value
1 , A      -  1  , A
1 , B      -  2  , A
2 , A      -  2  , B
3 , B      -  3  , C
```

The above example only shows the supposed content of the two files. It is not the actual structure. So, I am having two different files. I only used hyphen (-) to show that they are different files. No hyphen is present in the files.
I am already having the two csv files and their content is imported from the sql tables.
The content of each csv file looks like the following:

```
[id:1, value1:A, value2:B, value3:C]
[id:1, value1:A, value2:G, value3:K]
[id:2, value1:A, value2:G, value3:K]
```

Where id, value1,value2,value3
it used to be the column names of the sql tables.

So I am having those csv files and what I need is to compare their content.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question needs some work to get help. When you use "diff" command from bash, you are no more using groovy for comparison.  Please edit the question to include some sample lines from first and second file, and expected output.

Comment: you can load each file as list Strings, split each of them and compare.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Jayan. I have edited it and I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: does order of output matter?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. As long as there is the ID, I can identify them even in mixed order.

Answer (score 0):

```
def csvParser = {String filePath->
    File csvFile = new File("/home/sachin/Projects/scripts/groovyScript/csv.csv")
    def keys = []
    def data = []
    csvFile.eachLine{line, i ->
      if(i==1) {
        keys = line.split(',')
        return
      }
      def map = [:]
      line.split(',').eachWithIndex{val, j-> 
        map[keys[j]] = val
      }
      data.push(map)    
    }
    data
}
def data = ["path1","path2"].collect {csvParser(it)}
def extraInFirst = data[0] - data[1]
def extraInSecond = data[1] - data[0]
def common = (data[0] - (data[0] - data[1]))
```

Expected input format:

```
ID, Value 
1 , A     
1 , B     
2 , A     
3 , B
```

Now you have all the required values in `extraInFirst`, `extraInSecond` and `common`

It checks the difference in every field. if any field is different then it will not be a part of common. I hope you can generate any output from it.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your answer Sachin. I appreciate it. However, I think I still haven't made it completely clear, so I added more comments in my post under the "EDIT:"  . Your suggestions for splitting and mapping sounds very good . Bearing in mind what I have explained in the EDIT, do you have any idea of how I could implement it? There are two files and maybe I would need to  to split both files. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no two lines are the same in a file, my approach would be to create a Set of Maps for each text file, where each line is represented by a Map. The Maps created are hashable (but not `Comparable`), so I would use this property to compare them.

```
Set<Map> left = parseTextFile("/home/testFolder/file1.txt")
Set<Map> right = parseTextFile("/home/testFolder/file2.txt")

Set<Map> inBoth = left.findAll { it in right }
Set<Map> onlyInLeft = left.findAll { !(it in inBoth) }
Set<Map> onlyInRight = right.findAll { !(it in inBoth) }

Set<Map> parseTextFile(String fileName){
    new File(fileName).collect { String line ->
        line.trim()[1..-2].split(',').collectEntries { it.trim().split(":") }
    }
}
```

This approach runs in roughly *O(n)* where *n* is the number of lines of the longer file.
As great as it looks, I would advise against using the `minus()` operator on non-`Comparable` objects. The time-complexity would increase to *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*, which would be noticeable for 4000 rows.